# Gmail API - missing snoozed emails (common use case requirement)

Tags: gmail-api

I'm sure that we, like many other partners using the Gmail API to support common use cases around Gmail.  With the new Snoozed (and follow-up) email features we are unable to see these message in the inbox (i.e. at least with the correct date).

Is this something that is planned for the Gmail API?

I would really like to lobby for this functionality as when you pull the Gmail Inbox, it is missing this info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack is not google support we cant tell you what google plans to add to their system.

Comment: Stack overflow cant tell you what Google has planed.  Even if a Googler did answer your question they are probably under NDA and couldnt tell you even if they knew the answer. try submitting a feature request. [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566264)